# What are some options for XML on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

I have implemented NSXMLParser in my app and I am reviewing alternatives. My complaints about NSXMLParser are that it's convoluted to implement for simple files, and it's not the zippiest thing around either.

So far I've identified:

- [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML)
- [Objective-XML](http://www.metaobject.com/blog/2009/01/iphone-xml-performance.html)

Any others?

And what's your experience with these?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) in our app, specifically the [xmlTextReader](http://xmlsoft.org/xmlreader.html) API. It's a stream reader, which allows for much simpler code than a SAX reader (no callbacks, etc.) and doesn't put the whole document tree in memory like a DOM reader.

Comment: did you write a wrapper for xmlTextReader?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good example in the developer portal called XMLPerformance. It tells you how to parse xml files effectively using both libxml2 and NSXMLParser.

I am using it in one of my apps and the thing works great. I have some 600 items in my XML but the view hardly takes 1 sec to load using the methods provided in the example (without consuming much memory!)

Comment: That's a good example, been there done that. But my intent is to discover additional XML libraries available. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Came across this on one of the posts - Jim Dovey's written his own xml parser (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826281/better-performance-with-libxml2-or-nsxmlparser-on-the-iphone/842549#842549)