# Call C methods from C++/Java/C# code?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

Many of today's programming languages are based on C; like C++, C#, Java, Objective-C. So could I call a C method from C++ code? Or call C from Java or C#? Or is this goal out of reach and unreasonable? Please include a quick code sample for my and everyone else's understanding.

Comment: "…are based on C; like…C#, Java…" -- Are they? I think this is limited to curly braces and semicolons in those cases.

Comment: agree, syntax resemblance does not mean they are based on C even if they could be (or could have been as C++); C has no methods. C++ and Objective-C can call C functions and link to C-written libraries without problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++,C#, Objective-C, and Java can all call C routines. Here are a few links that will give you an overview of the process needed to call C from each language you asked about.

- [Calling C from Java](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.13/13.09/CallingCCodefromJava/index.html)
- [Calling C
  from C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)
- [Calling C from C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301501.aspx)
- [Calling C from Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method)

Comment: Can it call C routines from just compiled C code. Or does the C code have to be in a library?

Comment: C++ and Objective-C can compile C, as they are both supersets. C# and Java will require C code to exist in libs

Comment: the article about java is not about calling c from java but calling java from c

Answer (score 2):

An example of calling C from C++. Save this C function in a file called a.c:

```
int f() {
   return 42;
}
```

and compile it:

```
gcc -c a.c
```

which will produce a file called a.o. Now write a C++ program in a file called main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" int f();

int main() {
   std::cout << f() << std::endl;
}
```

and compile and link with:

```
g++ main.cpp a.o -o myprog
```

which will produce an execuatable called myprog which prints 42 when run.

Answer (score 1):

To Call C Methods In Java...

there a Keyword "native" in Which You can write machine-dependent C code and invoke it from Java....

Basically it creates a DLL file..then u have to load it in ur program...

a nice example [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip23.html)....

Answer (score 0):

To call C methods from Java, there are multiple options, including:

- [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) - Java Native Access. Free. Easy to use. Hand-declaration of Java classes and interfaces paralleling existing C structs and functions. Slower than JNI - by a few hundred nanoseconds per call.
- [JNI](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) - Java Native Interface. Free. Fastest option. Requires a layer of native glue code between your Java code and the native functions you want to call.
- [JNIWrapper](http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper) - Commercial product, similar to JNA.

Answer (score 0):

To call C/C++ from Java, also give a look at [BridJ](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/) (it's like JNA with C++ and better performance).