# Raise an NSDecimalNumber to a negative power

Tags: iphone, nsdecimalnumber

I need an equivalent to C's pow() function that will work with NSDecimalNumbers. With pow you can use negative numbers e.g. `pow(1514,-1234)`, with NSDecimal's decimalNumberByRaisingToPower: method, you are forced to use an NSUInteger which seems to require a positive value.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
[decimalNumber decimalNumberByRaisingToPower:-217.089218];
```

or

```
[decimalNumber decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:-217];
```

without crashing from overflow or underflow exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematically, a^(-b) == 1/(a^b). Therefore, if you just need to raise to a negative *integral* power,

```
decimalNumber = [decimalNumber decimalNumberByRaisingToPower:1234];
decimalNumber = [[NSDecimalNumber one] decimalNumberByDividingBy:decimalNumber];
```

For non-integral powers, there's no way except (1) implement the `pow()` algorithm yourself or by 3rd party libraries, or (2) performing the calculation in floating point (thus losing precisions).

Comment: It is an integral power in this case, your answer is perfect

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me.  What am I missing? 
9^(-2) = 3; 1/(9^2) = 1/27;

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, you appear to be correct about decimalNumberByRaisingToPower, but, from the Apple docs:

> (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberByMultiplyingByPowerOf10:(short)power

That's not unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert decimalNumber to its doubleValue and then just call the pow function of C++. I haven't tried it but I think it should work.
Refer: [Calling Objective-C method from C++ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method) for mixing c++ and objective c.