# How to retrieve Objective-C variable from C++ method?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ipad

I mixed some C++ codes with Objective-C in class with .mm extension.

I synthesized some variables in Objective-C, and I want to retrieve those variables in C++ methods. How to do that?

I tried [self aVariable], this->aVariable to retrieve the synthesized variables, but failed.

Comment: Pass them as parameters, perhaps?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed my problem after reading this post:

[Calling Objective-C method from C++ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method)

Comment: Why does `self` need to be typed as `void*`? Just do `void doSomething(id self)`. Of course, you could have understood all of this instantly by actually knowing any C, or by reading Apple's guide to Objective-C.

Comment: I tried your suggestion - void doSomething(id self), but it does not compile. "void *self" works, but I don't know why, since I am new in C++.

Comment: @user403015: what error(s) do you get when compiling? If you give us sufficient information, we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use self in a C++ class.
this->aVariable doesn't say anything.  It doesn't say whether you are trying to call a method.  In fact it doesn't do anything with aVariable.

I assume the method is attached to an objective-C object.  If so call it as follows from the C++ class:

```
[aVariable <method>];
```

Comment: Hey, I don't understand what you mean. Would you please explain in more details ?

Comment: @User: TBH I'm not sure what YOU are doing ... post some code