# Writing a C++ Wrapper around Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, wrapper, objective-c++

I want to call and work with Objective-C classes from within a C++ project on OS X. It is time to start moving towards all Objective-C, but we need to do this over some time.

How does one go about accomplishing this? Can anyone shed some light and provide an example?

Comment: Are you trying to call Foundation (non-UI) objects or AppKit (UI) objects? Are you calling `NSApplicationMain()` in `main()` or are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Objective-C method from C++ method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method)

Comment: There is an objective-c++ tag on SO that you should check out as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c++

Comment: @Rob Napier - Both Foundation and App Kit. Filesystem calls and dialog boxes for opening files, saving, alerts, etc.

Answer (score 9):

[Objective-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B) is a superset of C++, just as Objective-C is a superset of C. It is supported by both the gcc and clang compilers on OS X and allows you to instantiate and call Objective-C objects & methods from within C++. As long as you hide the Objective-C header imports and types within the implementation of a C++ module, it won't infect any of your "pure" C++ code.

`.mm` is the default extension for Objective-C++. Xcode will automatically do the right thing.

So, for example, the following C++ class returns the seconds since Jan 1., 1970:

```
//MyClass.h

class MyClass
{
  public:
    double secondsSince1970();
};

//MyClass.mm

#include "MyClass.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

double MyClass::secondsSince1970()
{
  return [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
}

//Client.cpp

...
MyClass c;
double seconds = c.secondsSince1970();
```

You will quickly find that Objective-C++ is even slower to compile than C++, but as you can see above, it's relatively easy to isolate its usage to a small number of bridge classes.

Answer (score 9):

I think it was [Phil Jordan](http://philjordan.eu/article/strategies-for-using-c++-in-objective-c-projects) that really put forward the best C++ wrapped Obj-C formula. However, I think the latter, C++ wrapped by Obj-C is more useful. I'll explain why below.

### Wrapping an Objective-C object with C++

#### Person.h - The Obj-C header

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end
```

#### PersonImpl.h - The C++ header

```
namespace people {
    struct PersonImpl;

    class Person
    {
    public:
        Person();
        virtual ~Person();

        std::string name();
        void setName(std::string name);

    private:
        PersonImpl *impl;
    };
}
```

#### Person.mm - The Obj-C++ implementation

```
#import "Person.h"

#import "PersonImpl.h"

namespace people {
   struct PersonImpl
   {
      Person *wrapped;
   };

   Person::Person() :
   impl(new PersonImpl())
   {
      impl->wrapped = [[Person alloc] init];
   }

   Person::~Person()
   {
      if (impl) {
         [impl->wrapped release]; // You should turn off ARC for this file. 
                                  // -fno-objc-arc in Build Phases->Compile->File options
      }

      delete impl;
   }

   std::string Person::name()
   {
      return std::string([impl->wrapped UTF8String]); 
   }

   void Person::setName(std::string name)
   {
      [impl->wrapped setName:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:name.c_str()]];
   }
}

@implementation Person
@end
```

### Wrapping a C++ object with Objective-C

I often find the real problem isn't getting C++ to talk to Obj-C code, it's switching back and forth between the two where things get ugly. Imagine an object that needs to have C++-only items, but the basic object details are filled out in Obj-C land. In this case, I write the object in C++ and then make it so I can talk to it in Obj-C.

#### Person.h - The C++ header

```
namespace people
{
   struct PersonImpl;

   class Person
   {
   public:
      Person();
      Person(Person &otherPerson);
      ~Person();
      std:string name;

   private:
      PersonImpl *impl;
   }
}
```

#### Person.cpp - The C++ implementation

```
namespace people
{
   struct PersonImpl
   {
       // I'll assume something interesting will happen here.
   };

   Person::Person() :
   impl(new PersonImpl())
   {
   }

   Person::Person(Person &otherPerson) :
   impl(new PersonImpl()),
   name(otherPerson.name)
   {
   }

   ~Person()
   {
      delete impl;
   }
}
```

#### Person.h - The Obj-C header

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic, readonly) void *impl;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@end
```

#### Person.mm - The Obj-C++ implementation

```
@interface Person ()
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) std::shared_ptr<people::Person> impl;
@end

@implementation Person

- (instancetype)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      self.impl = std::shared_ptr<people::Person>(new people::Person());
   }

   return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithPerson:(void *)person
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      people::Person *otherPerson = static_cast<people::Person *>(person);
      self.impl = std::shared_ptr<people::Person>(new people::Person(*otherPerson));
   }

   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
   // If you prefer manual memory management
   // delete impl;
}

- (void *)impl
{
   return static_cast<void *>(self.impl.get());
}

- (NSString *)name
{
   return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:self.impl->name.c_str()];
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)name
{
   self.impl->name = std::string([name UTF8String]);
}

@end
```

#### Regarding the void *

The second you stepped into the land of C++ you were going to feel some pain if you want to avoid your whole project being littered with `.mm` files. So, let's just say, if you don't think it is ever necessary to get your C++ object back out, or reconstitute the Obj-C object with the C++ object you can remove that code. It is important to note that the second you remove the `Person` instance from the Obj-C code through the `void *` method you had better make your own copy with the copy constructor or the pointer will become invalid.

Answer (score 3):

First rename your files from *.m to *.mm so you get Objective-C++

I have not tired this, so it is speculation (I will tonight):

As all Objective-C++ objects (that are reference counted) are controlled via pointers so you can write a special destructor for shared pointer.

```
template<typename T>
struct ObjCDestruct
{
    void operator()(T* obj)
    {
        [obj release];
    }
};
```

Now you can stick your Objective-C obects in a boost::shared_ptr

```
// FuncFile.M
//
int func()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<MyX, ObjCDestruct<MyX> >  data([[MyX alloc] init]);

    [data.get() doAction1:@"HI"];
}
```

Comment: if you wanted to be extra-snazzy, you'd subclass `type_traits` for is_ObjC_obj, and specialize on that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question [Calling Objective-C method from C++ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method)

You will need to have some objective-c classes to wrap the code and expose with a C function.