# How to Convert C++ code to Objective C Code in iphone?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have some pure C++ codes are have I want to change the code as objective C code format. How can do this there is an any tools are there or else how can i do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compile C++ code to work on the iphone directly. Keep your core as pure C++, and write the bits that need to talk to objective-C libraries as objective-C++ ( `.mm` rather than `.m` IIRC ).

Comment: I know this but my thought is i want to change my code pure objective c format

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible automatically to translate C++ to Objective-C in the sense that you are asking. Picking just one of the large semantic differences at random, C++ allows multiple inheritance and Objective-C doesn't. You therefore can't map the inheritance graph of C++ onto the inheritance graph of Objective-C.

What you'd do if you were converting manually would be to switch to protocols where what you're meaning to establish is a published set of permissible communications and object composition where you wanted an object to combine some other logic. You'd probably keep the main line of inheritance in a lot of cases. However you're not going to find a tool capable of automating that process.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following question :[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504559/writing-a-c-wrapper-around-objective-c)

and you can compile c++ code directly by changing vc.m to vc.mm