# Returning objective-c from c++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c, header

I’m developing in a mixed objective-c and c++ project.

I have a class in which in the definition (.mm) I’m working with both objective-c and c++, but in the header, I just have c++ code…

The issue is I need a function to return a objective-c class, and I can’t since the hpp it’s just c++.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504559/writing-a-c-wrapper-around-objective-c ??  Let me know if you disagree.

Comment: Without giving us an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's difficult to tell what you want to achieve.