# How to use iOS framework with Unity?

Tags: ios, frameworks, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use an iOS native framework inside Unity, but I don't know how.

Inside my C# script, I call a native function like this :

```
[DllImport ("__Internal")]
    private static extern void writeHello();

    void Start () {
        writeHello();
    }
```

I have drag the iOS framework inside my project like this :

[Link to my image](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/583990ScreenShot20121107at102612AM.png)

But when I deploy my app on iPad, xCode showing this error :

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:   "_writeHello", referenced
>   from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I don't understand why, and I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible.
Help! :)

Thanks,
Sennin

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Rajesh yes, see my answer below ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to this post : [Calling Objective-C method from C++ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method)

By doing like that :

```
void myWriteHello( void *test) {
    [(id)test writeHello];
}

- (void) writeHello
{
    NSLog(@"Hello World!");
}
```

and calling my C function from Unity

Answer (score 3):

The iOS framework must be put in the xCode generated project, not in unity.

And the framework's functions must be wrapped in an `extern "C"` block (as shown [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/137156-Calling-an-Objective-C-function-in-an-iPad-app-from-Unity)).

Then you will be able to use it in C# with `dllimport`.

Comment: HI, and thanks for your response. The problem is that my writeHello function is written in objective-c native language, so my writeHello file is a .m, can I use the symbol "extern"?

Answer (score 1):

The doc says that all files with extensions .a,.m,.mm,.c,.cpp located in the Assets/Plugins/iOS folder will be merged into the generated Xcode project automatically. The docs also says that subfolders are currently not supported, so, in your example, the "framework-helloUnity.framework" folder will be ignored.

It is important to note that .m files default to C-style bindings, while .mm files default to C++-style bindings. In other word, unless you use the `extern "C"` keyword, as Heilo suggested, your functions won't be found if you put them in .mm or .cpp files.

In other words, if you put the following:

```
void writeHello() {}
```

in a file named `Assets/Plugins/iOS/myTestFile.m`, your code should compile.

Answer (score 0):

You have write the following function in your Xcode project any class
extern "C" 
{
   -(void) writeHello
   {

}
}