# Using a delegate to communicate between a C++ class and an Objective-C class?

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a thread class (C++) instance running. When the thread has finished its operation, I want to communicate with one of my UIView objects (Objective-C). Would this be possible via a delegate?

Comment: No, I want to notify one of my UIView (objective-C). Not related to UIWebView or JavaScripts. thanks

Comment: check this other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method) and the main answer

Comment: @tkanzakic thanks for the link, How about calling dispatch_async() from C++, it seems working. Any idea?

Comment: accordingly to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_async.3.html) you can do it, I never try it before

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why wouldn't it be?

When compiling in Objective-C++ mode (.mm file extension) you can freely mix Objective-C, C and C++ code, classes and objects.

Just make sure to perform any GUI stuff on the main thread.