# Use objc object inside c++ code?

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, xcode5

I have an ObjC class called Log. In this class I have a public static method call error.

I want to call this method from my C++ code (if possible like this: Log::error(string);).

I was going around the internet and stack overflow but I found only this:

http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++

and this:

[Calling Objective-C method from C++ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method)
(I tried to use the first method but I don't know how to create the void *objectiveCObject variable.)

Comment: I also have a C++ class called `Log` which is used from both C++ and Objective-C++ and this wasn't an issue for me as I implemented the class using C++, and not Objective-C++, which is kind of the *lowest common denominator* of the two languages.  Would that approach work for you?

Comment: I wanted to do it with objc code as I'm trying to gain more exp in it.

Comment: Sure, but it's clumsy, especially for a logging class which is used frequently and in many places.  The only real mechanism available to allow C++ to Objective-C is a *callback mechanism* using a C/C++ function.  This gets more complicated if you want to use instance methods as you have to pass around the class pointer as `void *`.  If you want to gain Objective-C experience then choose something else to do it with.

Comment: My question was how to create that pointer in the c++ code. I know it is an overkill but the Log class is just one of many that will use this functionality and interconnection.

Comment: OK, I will post an answer on my take on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the header file for the `Log` class you need to provide a callback mechanism with C-linkage that can be used by C++ and you need to guard against C++ seeing the Objective-C stuff.  This header can then be shared by both C++ and Objective-C.  An alternative to this is to provide a separate header file and implementation file solely for the use of C++, however that adds more cruft to the implementation.

As per your comment, I have added C++ accessible methods to create and destroy the Objective-C `Log` object, however I'm certain for this to work you'll have to use MRR rather than ARC so that you can manage the lifetime.  So you you will need to compile `Log.m` with `-fobjc-no-arc`.

Log.h:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#else // !__OBJC__
#include <stdarg.h>
// And maybe other C++ headers...
#endif // __OBJC__

typedef void *ObjcLog;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern ObjcLog *logCreate(const char *filename);
extern void logDestroy(ObjcLog *logObj);
extern void logInfo(ObjcLog *logObj, const char *msg, ...);
extern void logError(ObjcLog *logObj, const char *msg, ...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // extern "C"
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
@interface Log : NSObject {
    // stuff
}

// Other stuff

@end
#endif // __OBJC__
```

Log.m:

```
#import "Log.h"

ObjcLog *logCreate(const char *filename) {
    // Assumes [Log initWithFilename:]
    Log *log = [[Log alloc] initWithFilename:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:filename]];
    return (ObjcLog *)log;
}

void logDestroy(ObjcLog *logObj) {
    Log *log = (Log *)logObj;
    [log release];
}

void logInfo(ObjcLog *logObj, const char *msg, ...) {
    char buffer[8192];
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, msg);
    vsprintf(buffer, msg, va);
    va_end(va);

    Log *log = (Log *)logObj;
    // Assumes [Log info:]
    [log info:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer]];
}

void logError(ObjcLog *logObj, const char *msg, ...) {
    char buffer[8192];
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, msg);
    vsprintf(buffer, msg, va);
    va_end(va);

    Log *log = (Log *)context;
    // Assumes [Log error:]
    [log error:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer]];
}

@implementation Log

...

@end
```

Your C++ code should then be able to use the Objective-C `Log` object like this:

```
ObjcLog *logObj = logCreate("/path/to/file.log");
...
logInfo(logObj, "The answer is %d.  What is the question?", 42);
...
logDestroy(logObj);
```

I would probably favour the creation of a C++ wrapper class for the Objective-C class, which will make it easier to manage the lifetime of the object and simplify access to it.  However I will avoid adding it here as it will likely just complicate something that is already over-complicated.

Comment: Is there any way I can init it in the .cpp file? If you could share the code for it that will be great.

Comment: @MartiMarkov OK, I have updated my answer.  That actually makes the implementation much neater and more obvious.  Take note about not using ARC when implementing `Log`.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Log is mainly static (singleton if not accessing the static methods). You mean for the ARC to not remove it and the c code to use it after it was removed?

Comment: @MartiMarkov Yeah - you are controlling the lifetime of the object from C++ so you want to disable ARC for that class.

Comment: Ummm.. How do you disable ARC for a specific class? :D I haven't played that much with ObjC's memory management.

(BTW this is why I wanted to use this implementation I learned a lot from your answers. :) )

Comment: @MartiMarkov See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project