# Managing objective-C objects with c++ std::unique_ptr<> or std::shared_ptr<>

Tags: c++, objective-c, memory-management, raii

Objective-C can be mixed with c++ to some extent and [can be called to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1061005/1792701). But Objective-C objects still are more or less manually managed, and RAII idiom is entirely absent from the language. I wonder if it is possible to manage the lifetimes of Objective-C objects with c++ smart pointers. Specially now that both boost `scoped_ptr` and `shared_ptr` have been added to the C++11 standard

Comment: My knowledge about C++ is much less than about Objective-C, so I might get your question completely wrong. But why would you need C++ smart pointers for Objective-C objects if you have ARC (automatic reference counting)?

Comment: ARC requires sending release messages explicitly. In C++ the equivalent decrement message is sent when the local instance variable goes out of scope (that is, the function using it returns or throws)

Comment: But with ARC, the *compiler* inserts the necessary retain/release messages into the compiled code. So from the programmers point of view, an object is released automatically if it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> But Objective-C objects still are more or less manually managed, and RAII idiom is entirely absent from the language.

I think this would seem to answer your question anyhow.  Because Objective-C objects are reference counted, they already fulfill the purpose smart pointers were created for: to divorce or tie the lifetime of an object from the scope of the method it's contained in.  `scoped_ptr`s can be recreated with autorelease pools, and `shared_ptr`s with `-retain`-`-release` or `strong` references.

But saying no is boring.  If you really want to mingle Objective-C and C++ like this, we'll need to first loosen the definition of "Objective-C object".  The runtime recognizes anything with an `isa` sitting as its first member as an object, and we can take advantage of that and write a simple C++ class with a corresponding object interface so it can be messaged:

```
@interface CFIObject : NSObject
- (void)doSomething;
@end

struct CFIObject_cxx {
    Class isa;
public:
    CFIObject_cxx() : isa([CFIObject class]) {}
~CFIObject_cxx() { printf("I'm dying!"); }
};

@implementation CFIObject
- (void)doSomething {
    NSLog("I did something.");
}
@end
```

We can now instantiate an instance of our C++ object and wrap it in a smart pointer, which I'm going to purposefully split into two methods to illustrate the lifetime of the object:

```
void func() {
    // Instantiate a smart pointer with our fake object.
    std::unique_ptr<CFIObject_cxx> cppObj (new CFIObject_cxx());
    id obj = (__bridge id)(cppObj.get());
    // The runtime thinks we're an object.
    [obj doSomething];
    // aaaand, it's out of scope.
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

As one would expect, this prints:

```
2013-12-22 17:23:22.681 Test[77528:303] I did something
I'm dying!
```

to the console.

If need be, the destructor could be outfitted to call through to `-dealloc` to simulate proper object destruction, but I hope you see that all of this is just wholly unnecessary, especially with ARC getting smarter with each release of CLANG.