# Notify C++ from Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c

We have created common C++ interface & have platform specific concrete implementation.
Now for iPad we do not seem to find any direct mechanism in objective C for notification. Apparently there does not seem to be any way in objective C to notify common C++ codes once HTTP response is received (to pass the response to common C++ codes).

Has anyone tried to notify C++ codes from Objective C passing an object?

Comment: Not very good variant, but if you don't find something better, you could use a pointer to some callback function implemented in C++ and call it from within your Obj C code on HTTP response event.

Comment: What do you mean by "notification" ? Probably you need to check the "Obj-C++" with `.mm` file extension

Comment: Hi Ivan,

Thanks for the quick response.
The idea of using pointer within objective C to a callback function implemented in C++ can help.Currently got stuck with some other work but we will surely try this route. We have never registered pointer this way, do you know of any such sample/example?

Thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

I d not understand what you mean with the "notify" thing but if you want to be able to call c++ from objective-c name the file .mm instead of .m. That makes it possible to use both c++ and objective-c in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

It's really unclear what you're asking,
anyway
**If you're trying to call C++ code from objective c**
Rename your objective c file to .mm extension
So for example if you have ViewController.m rename it to ViewController.mm

If you want to crate PIMPL, refer to this question,
[Calling Objective-C method from C++ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method)
The answer covers topics, how to interact from c++ to objective c objects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested link, we are supposed to do this also but the issue raised in my question is for reverse situation i.e. C++ from Objective C.
Looks like Ivan's comment might help.