# Rate App Functionality using cocos2d-x 3.2

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to Rate my app using Cocos2d-x 3.2 for both android and ios. I searched a lot on community & forums and at all possible places but I don't get proper results. Is there any free plugin available who can solve my problem easily? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using this, It may be a little old.
But, you can try and use this:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate

Comment: i guess its not available for cocos2d-x . is it ?

Comment: i don't understand your problem, you can call obj-c functions from c++ code ... if you need help with that, you can probably refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-method