# Node.js native macOS framework example

Tags: node.js, objective-c++, node.js-addon

Where is a clear, concise example of how to use Objective-C++ to access and use a native macOS framework in a Node.js native module?

For example: touch bar functionality

I would prefer for the example to be as short and simple as possible while still being clear. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the Objective-C bridge module (https://github.com/lukaskollmer/objc)? You might not even need to create a native module.

Comment: Whoa! That's neat! Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may write a node.js addon module in c++, but not Objective C.

If you have a c / c++ library api that allows you to play with the touch bar, you can write a node.js addon module in c++ that will expose this functionality to javascript.

I repeat node.js native addons can be written using c++, but not objective-C.

Comment: Can you call macOS frameworks from C++ directly without a bridge of some kind?

Comment: If you have a c / c++ library API to support the framework in question, then yes, you can.

Comment: Can you call Objective C from C++ and then call C++ from Node.js? I'm looking at [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061005/calling-objective-c-method-from-c-member-function)

Comment: Sure, you can make a c++ native module that calls objective C, no problem