# Speed Comparison: C++ vs Objective C

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, xcode, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective-C vs C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926728/objective-c-vs-c)

It is known that it is possible to write applications using C++ on Apple iOS platform, which can be especialy useful, when porting application.

Using C++ brings some obstacles comparing to Objective C in iOS. Apart from these obstacles, how is it with speed?

**Are C++ applications compiled for iOS running slove or faster than Objective C apps?**

I understand that the speed of an application depends on the app design. I would like to know if C++ compiled application for iOS (XCODE) add some extra code/workarounds to be compatible in environment where Objective C is native development platform.

In general, from architectural viewpoint, wich code delivers better performance (C++ or Objective C)?