# what kind of parser is NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone

what kind of parser is NSXMLParser.?

Is it dom parser or sax parser.

how many parsers are there?

Comment: It's SAX callback oriented rather than tree hierarchically stored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a SAX parser. There are a number of DOM XML parsers available for iOS, and the best guide I've seen is [How To Chose The Best XML Parser for your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

Answer (score 3):

NSXMLParser is [a wrapper around libxml2's SAX functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826281/better-performance-with-libxml2-or-nsxmlparser-on-the-iphone).