# iOS - Differences about NSXMLParser and libxml2

Tags: ios, ipad, xcode4, ios4, ios5

[better-performance-with-libxml2-or-nsxmlparser-on-the-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826281/better-performance-with-libxml2-or-nsxmlparser-on-the-iphone)

I've read that question and the answer about comparation of XML parser on iOS Apps Development. Well, actually i don't get what the point is.

My questions is, if I want to get and load huge XML data on my apps, larger than 200kb, what the best I could use..? is it NSXMLParser or libxml2..?

btw, I'm using Xcode 4.2 on iOS 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with the accepted answer to that question?

Basically, @zPesk says :

libxml was found to be a bit faster but harder to use because it's in C instead of objective-c.

I don't think it matters that much as long as you use SAX parsing instead of DOM parsing - the last thing you want to do with an XML document that big is to load it into memory all at once!

Comment: well, I want to know which one the best I could put on my app. Is there anyone know an issue while using NSXMLParser when develop on Xcode 4.2...?

Comment: I think the point of the answer is that it's a personal choice - do you need ultimate speed or do you want it to be easier to write code for? I've never had any problems with `NSXMLParser` if that's any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have used this resource in the past:

[How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

The post summarizes the differences between a number of different XML parsers for iOS.